# XSLT Identity template overriding

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, apply-templates

I need to remove some unwanted fields over a big response XML using XSL 1.0, and want to use apply-templates instead of for-each. Below is the code I tried but is not giving expected results i.e., unwanted fields are removed successfully but few other fields outside match also disappeared. Am I using identity template incorrectly.

Input XML:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:object xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:array name="BankDetails">
   <one>field1</one>
   <two>field2</two>
   <xsl:object>
   <date>1234-56-78</date>
   <Time>12345678</Time>
   </xsl:object>
   <xsl:object>
   <date>0000-00-00</date>
   <Time>00000000</Time>
   </xsl:object>
   <xsl:object>
   <date>0000-00-00</date>
   <Time>00000000</Time>
   </xsl:object>
   <xsl:object>
   <date>0000-00-00</date>
   <Time>00000000</Time>
   </xsl:object>
   <three>field3</three>
   <four>field4</four>
   <five>field5</five>
   <six>field6</six>
   </xsl:array>
   </xsl:object>
```

Applied XSLT:

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/TransformAlias"
    xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl"   result-prefix="xsl" />
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="xsl:object/xsl:array">    
           <xsl:for-each select="xsl:object[Time !='00000000']">
                <xsl:copy-of select = "."/>
           </xsl:for-each>  
   </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I got:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:object xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">    
       <xsl:object>        
           <date>1234-56-78</date>
            <Time>12345678</Time>
            </xsl:object>
   </xsl:object>
```

What is expected:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:object xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:array name="BankDetails">
        <one>field1</one>
        <two>field2</two>
        <xsl:object>
            <date>1234-56-78</date>
            <Time>12345678</Time>
        </xsl:object>
        <three>field3</three>
        <four>field4</four>
        <five>field5</five>
        <six>field6</six>
    </xsl:array>
   </xsl:object>
```

Comment: It's very bad practice to hijack a namespace such as `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform` for your own use. It will confuse the reader, and it could also confuse tools such as XML editors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is that you are copying only `xsl:object` elements that have the right `Time` - but not doing anything (i.e. copy or apply templates) for the other elements that are also children of the context `xsl:array` element (`one`, `two` etc). If you do not apply templates to them, then the identity transform template will not be applied to them.

You are  also not copying the context `xsl:array` element.

I would suggest you approach it from the opposite point-of-view:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/TransformAlias">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl"   result-prefix="xsl" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xsl:object[Time ='00000000']"/>   
          
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting Mike. You are correct, I was thinking it with focus on - removing elements using null check in for-each condition and then assuming other elements to be taken care by identity template.